# Apóstrofo ou aspas simples?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, sinais-gráficos

> 'Alguma coisa'

A frase acima está entre **apóstrofos** ou **aspas simples**?
Qual o correto dizer?

Comment: Jedaias, editei a pergunta, pois os dicionários não concordavam comigo :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neste caso eu chamaria de aspas simples. O que *eu* considero apóstrofo pode ser visualmente idêntico a elas, mas tem um sentido diferente. Em português, seria usado para indicar que uma palavra foi truncada, como em *copo d'água*. Acredito que não é só a aparência que define o nome do sinal gráfico, mas também sua função. Como a função é muito diferente, pode ficar confuso usar o mesmo nome para as duas coisas.

**Porém, os dicionários discordam de mim.** O [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/ap%C3%B3strofo) (link by @Jacinto) registra:

> [após descrever a aparência do sinal na acepção 1]:
>
> 2. Gram. O mesmo sinal, us. para abrir e fechar palavras ou expressões ou frases que representam significados de palavras, expressões ou frases antes mencionadas [Ex.: O termo do tênis e vôlei *ace*, 'saque que o adversário não alcança', não tem correspondente em português.]

Então seria só para casos em que "representam significados". Já as *aspas* têm muitos outros usos. E, pelo menos no Brasil, as aspas duplas podem ser convertidas em simples caso uma frase toda seja envolvida por novas aspas de citação.

O Houaiss inclui uma acepção equivalente, porém com a ressalva de que se trata de termo técnico da lexicografia e da linguística. O mais interessante no Houaiss é a nota etimilógica:

> lat.tar. *apostrŏphos*, emprt. gr. *apóstrophos*, ou 'sinal de elisão, de paráfrase', masc.substv. do adj. *apóstrophos,os,on* 'que voltou', do v. *apostréphō* 'voltar, fazer voltar; chamar'; f.hist. 1576 apostropho

O termo vem do grego, passando pelo latim até chegar ao português. Em grego significava sinal de elisão (supressão de letra) ou paráfrase, e era derivado de um verbo que significava "voltar, fazer voltar; chamar". Interessante essa origem, porque todos os significados dicionarizados têm mesmo relação com essa ideia de "retorno" de algo.

Comment: Eu também acho assim, o que implica que aspas simples vêm aos pares, e o apóstrofo não. Mas o [significado 2 do Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/ap%C3%B3strofo) confunde-me. Mas o Aulete parece ser o único dicionário a incluir esse significado.

Comment: Fiz umas alterações e complementos à luz dos dicionários.

Comment: Se é assim um termo tão técnico, talvez não valha muito a pena preocuparmo-nos com ele. Eu, escreveria o exemplo do aulete sem esses apóstrofos: O termo do tênis e vôlei 'ace', saque que o adversário não alcança, não (...) Ou então, *ace*, saque...

Comment: Ah! descobri. Vê no Houaiss o verbete *pontuar:* ’isto’ são dois apóstrofos; ‘esta outra coisa’ são aspas simples; os dois apóstrofos são iguais; as aspas simples, uma é uma rotação de de 180º da outra. Eu já tinha reparado há muito que o Houaiss punha os signficados (na parte da etimologia) entre dois sinais paralelos, em vez de um ser a inversão do outro típica das aspas, mas pensei que uma mera opção estilística; não é!

Answer (score 3):

O dicionário Houaiss mostra os vários sinais junto ao verbete *pontuação*. Então, para que se veja bem:

[image]

Os apóstrofos são simplesmente vírgulas elevadas; as aspas simples também, só que a primeira é invertida. É claro que esta diferença desaparece em certos editores de texto, como o do Stack Exchange, em que fica tudo 'assim', a menos que copiem do Word, por exemplo, dando ’isto’ e ‘isto’.

Se tiverem tudo reduzido aos tracinhos verticais, e quiserem dar o nome correto, podem atentar na função, como já explica o bfavareto. Pares de apóstrofos têm apenas um uso, que é assinalar o significado ou aceção de uma palavra. Ilustro com um exemplo do Houaiss (desabreviando algumas abreviaturas):

> **história** […] ETIMOLOGIA grego *historía,as* ’pesquisa, informação, relato, história’, pelo latim *historĭa,ae* ’a história, história universal, narração, conto, aventura’

Portanto, entre apóstrofos vêm os significados do grego *historía* e do latim *historĭa*. Isto é um uso muito especializado, mas nem é má convenção para se adotar aqui no site. Comparem, “*all* é ’tudo’ em inglês” e “clareza e concisão é tudo no inglês”.

Já as aspas simples servem para substituir as aspas duplas num texto que já está ele mesmo entre aspas duplas. Por exemplo, suponhamos que eu quero citar o trecho destacado abaixo de [*Casa-Grande & Senzala* de Gilberto Freyre](https://books.google.pt/books?id=RAYsAAAAYAAJ&q=%22%C3%A9%20verdade%20que%20desde%20esses%20tempos%20remotos%20o%20senhor%20se%20ado%C3%A7ou%20em%20sinh%C3%B4%20em%20nhonh%C3%B4%20em%20ioi%C3%B4%22&dq=%22%C3%A9%20verdade%20que%20desde%20esses%20tempos%20remotos%20o%20senhor%20se%20ado%C3%A7ou%20em%20sinh%C3%B4%20em%20nhonh%C3%B4%20em%20ioi%C3%B4%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDkZHOg4XjAhXnRBUIHQ0YA8gQ6AEILDAA):

[image]

Como já vou delimitar a citação pelas minhas aspas duplas, substituo as aspas duplas do original por aspas simples. Escreve Gilberto Freyre: “É verdade que desde esses tempos remotos o ‘senhor’ se adoçou em ‘sinhô’, em nhonhô, em ‘ioiô’.”

A apóstrofo individual, que não se confunde com as aspas, serve ainda para coisas como *mãe d’água*, *li n’Os Lusíadas* (em alternativa a *li em Os Lusíadas*) ou *Jesus, é a fé n’Ele que nos salva* (em vez de *nele*). Estes usos vêm previstos no [Acordo Ortográfico de 1990, Base XVIII](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=acordo&version=1990).

Comment: Já agora, como é que se colocam uns e outros com um teclado QWERTY PT?

Comment: @João, no meu computador, que é QWERTY, a mesma tecla serve de aspa simples e apóstrofo (tecla do ponto de interrogação). Isto é para Word: para aspas simples é o normal, quando primes a tecla a seguir a espaço, o Word abre aspa, isto é escreve-te uma vírgula invertida elevada; após letra, fecha aspa (vírgula elevada normal). Então para começar com apóstrofo, escrevo uma letra qualquer, seguido do apóstrofo (aí, come é a seguir a letra o Word "pensa" que estás a fechar a aspa), depois volto atrás e apago a letra.

Comment: Ou então prime Alt digitando ao mesmo tempo 0 1 4 6 no teclado numérico auxiliar. Aí ele escreve-te um apóstrofo independentemente do que estiver antes.