# Quais as diferenças das variações das aspas?

Tags: ortografia, diferenças

Acabei de ter essa dúvida e essa [pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/ap%c3%b3strofo-ou-aspas-simples) não aborda todas as variações das aspas.

Exemplo:

- `'` e `‘ ... ’`;
- `"..."` e `“ ... ”`;

Ainda tem estas outras variações que achei no [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%B3strofo) (ignore os `i`s acentuados):

[image: Variações]

Repare que não são visualmente iguais...

É só o estilo da fonte ou são diferentes mesmo?

Como denominar cada uma delas e quais as diferenças na utilização?

Comment: eu tenho dúvida se isso é realmente uma pergunta sobre a Lingua Portuguesa, ou algo em geral. Por isso, tbm não tenho a certeza do local correto para essa questão.

Comment: Como a [tag:ortografia] sugere, a pergunta tem como objetivo principal a escrita correta dos sinais gráficos citados. Tal como suas denominações. Se trata de escrita, leitura, significados de palavras e afins, não vejo lugar melhor para tal pergunta. Até porque "*algo em geral*" é bem genérico, o que pode incluir a língua portuguesa. xD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use '', "", «», — or italic?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/when-to-use-or-italic)

Comment: Então e as aspas originais, as «» que têm uma tecla reservada no teclado e tudo?!? Racismo dos carateres... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que o próprio verbete da Wikipedia deixa claro que se tratam de 5 sinais (incluindo o apóstrofo, mas não as aspas) -- ou 3 sinais, ignorando as duas versões de acentos agudos sobre os "i"s -- apenas em fontes diferentes:

[image]

Também como indicado na imagem, os nomes dos sinais são:

- **apóstrofo**, cujo uso é esclarecido [nessa questão](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1613/2764)
- [**ápice**](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/%C3%A1pice/), que se usa, e.g., para indicar tonicidade em palavras
- [**plica**](http://www.aulete.com.br/plica), às vezes sinônimo de acento agudo, pode ser usado como o ápice

Comment: Discordo. Entendo que o verbete da Wikipédia deixa claro que são sinais diferentes, e mostra-o com uma imagem: primeiro os seis sinais `Í’?′i´` em Arial, depois em Calibri, em Tahoma, Times New Roman, e Linux Libertine. Não só fontes diferentes representam o mesmo sinal de formas diferentes, como a mesma fonte representa sinais diferentes de formas diferentes.

Comment: @ANeves Que são cinco (você vê seis?) sinais diferentes é bastante óbvio, está explícito na legenda também. Mas me parece incontestável que são 5 sinais diferentes em 5 fontes diferentes.

Comment: Pedi para ignorarem os coitadinhos dos is...

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga- Qual exatamente é sua dúvida, então? Se `plica`, `ápice` e `apóstrofo` são sinônimos? Não são e, correspondentemente, geralmente têm representações diferentes (numa dada fonte).

Comment: @stafusa quero saber seus nomes e quando devo usar cada um deles. E se a questão das diferenças visuais, como por exemplo as citadas na pergunta, são apenas diferentes fontes ou se é uma variação de verdade.

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga- Mas os nomes estão lá: apóstrofo, ápice e plica. Incluí agora na resposta, mas são palavras que se encontram em dicionários e na wikipedia.

Comment: Plica é usado na Matemática para expressar ângulo em minutos. Inclusive no sistema internacional. Esse é o uso da plica pelo que estudei.

Comment: @DanielBandeira Cf. [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/plica): `pli·ca 2. [Ortografia]  Acento agudo (´) que se põe sobre uma letra e a que em álgebra se chama linha.` Mas acho que me lembro de já ter visto o uso que você menciona. Acredito que não existe uma grande padronização no uso e nomenclatura de todos esses símbolos.

Comment: @DanielBandeira Pois é, também estranhei, e a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/plica) não menciona o significado de agudo — contudo, ele é mencionado, além do Priberam, pelo Houaiss, pelo [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/plica/) e pelo [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/plica), então acabo aceitando que essa é a nomenclatura.

Comment: Acho forçado igualar plica com acento agudo, embora graficamente sejam parecidos, a posição de cada sobre o grafo muda; sendo que a plica, distintamente do acento agudo, atua sobre valor numérico/medida. Priberam é um excelente dicionário, mas talvez tenham exagerado na simplicidade ao significá-lo.